# How to get the pixel value from the acceleration of UIAccelerometer?

Tags: ios, uiaccelerometer

I've calculated the velocity from the acceleration of UIAcceleometer,
and I want to move the UIView in opposite of the distance which the device moves but same distance.
For example, if I move the device to right, the UIView should go left with the same distance on screen.

The problem is that the UIAcceleration shows the G value, I can only convert it to meter.
How can I transform the meter value to local coordinate on screen?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think that feature is implemented in iOS. It'll be trial & error tens of times over and over again until you find the correct relationship between G and point (don't use pixels).